# removing unnecessary .csv rows before inserting into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Is it possible to delete/remove unnecessary rows in CSV file before inserting/importing into database? I have upload file.

for example.

I want to delete/remove blank rows in CSV,
or I want to insert only the data in my database fields.

Thanks much!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I tried inserting CSV data in database but sometimes it wont work because the script reads unnecessary rows. thanks

Comment: What I meant is show us your code.

Comment: Well then probe the individual rows, or use FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES if using the file() function (we don't know).

Comment: You can use MySQL to do this: `DELETE FROM table WHERE column = '';` after import.

Comment: I already put my code in SO but sadly it still not working to me. that's why I have collecting some ideas again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you load the data into a staging table, and then use SQL to do the filtering.

After all, you are putting the data into a database.  Databases are very good at such manipulation

Comment: I tried that already. but it doesn't work on me. please this scrshot http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11k8602&s=6